# Store a textbox value to two managed bean classes

Tags: jsp, jsf, jsf-1.2, managed-bean

I have a textbox and two managed bean classes, namely, LoginMB and QuestionMB. Both of these have a parameter named login_id. How do I store the textbox value in both Managed beans at once?

I am using jsf version 1.2 and jsp pages.

Comment: Thank you all.I did it without using facescontext!Thanks.While submitting the form i used

`<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{loginMB.save}">
<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{QuestionMB.login_id}"
value="#{LoginMB.login_id}" />
</h:commandButton>`

Answer (score 0):

You can save the value of the TextBox in a session variable and then store it in your beans like this,

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put(key,object);
```

or in your commandButton click you can pass it as a parameter and save it in your second bean.

[Here is an example of passing a parameter](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/4-ways-to-pass-parameter-from-jsf-page-to-backing-bean/)

Answer (score 0):

When I need to do something like this I directly send the value to one bean and load the other bean inside the first one. After this you can set the value to the second one.

I will give you a example if the bean is in application context, you should do small changes according to your needs.

```
first bean {

ApplicationView appView = BeanUtil.findBean("applicationView", FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());

appView.setYourValue();

}


import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

public class BeanUtil {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T findBean(String beanName, FacesContext context) {
        return (T) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{" + beanName + "}", Object.class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using [binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/inputText.html) attribute to create a component in the second bean and set the corresponding value from the component into login_id ?

Another way is to create a valueChangeListener for the second bean that gets called whenever textbox changes, and in the listener update login_id value in backing bean.